# Is it possible to filter a list using boolean test specifier?

Tags: applescript

I'm interested: is it possible to filter a list using boolean test specifier?

Like this for example:

```
set allList to every message of mailbox "Sent Messages" of iCloud account "iCloud"
-- gives an execution error: 
set filtList2 to every item of allList whose subject contains "test"
```

while this line works as expected:

```
set filtList1 to every message of mailbox "Sent Messages" of iCloud account "iCloud" whose subject contains "test"
```

I understand, that I can filter the list using a loop:

```
set filtList3 to {}
    repeat with aMessage in allList
        if subject of aMessage contains "test" then
            set end of filtList3 to aMessage
        end if
    end repeat
end tell
```

Why boolean test specifier gives me an error on a list?

Thank you!

Comment: The whose/where/that query (filter reference form) only applies to application objects, and can't be used to filter AppleScript objects such as lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, it turns out, that boolean test specifiers for lists are not implemented in AppleScript, so one should use loops instead.